# Can't resolve 'buffer' in 'C:\Portal\\node_modules\string_decoder\node_modules\safe-buffer'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to build my angular project and getting below error:

```
Build Command: node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

My Angular version is :@angular/cli: "^8.2.2".

I tried reinstalling nodejs 12.13 and deleted npm-cache and still it did not work

Error:-

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/string_decoder/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in
```

Comment: Can my answer be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 13):

I got it working by installing the missing modules.

```
npm install assert --save
npm install buffer --save
```

Answer from https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/issues/417.

Answer (score 0):

```
"browser": {
    "buffer": false
}
```

in your package.json should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me, in React. You are going to need to locate your `webpack.config.js` file. For me, it was located in: `./node_modules/react-scripts/config`

Running into this error, among many other related errors, I did the following within the file's `resolve` object:

1. Remove `modules`
2. Add `fallback: {},`

As it pertains to this issue, you need to install the `buffer` package using `npm install buffer` and adjust your fallback object property so that it appears as such:

```
fallback: {
    "buffer": require.resolve('buffer'),
},
```

You may need to upgrade to webpack 5, using `npm install webpack@latest`

Another solution altogether seems to be using `react-app-rewired` to implement these changes to webpack. From what I can gather it does the same exact thing, however with the above method, I was able to gain familiarity with the issue without circumventing it entirely — and without adding an additional layer of complexity.